# Arbitrary intervals free of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

"Show that there for an arbitrary positive integer *k* there exist *k* consecutive integers none of which is a prime."

How would one go about doing this? It's an exercise in a book on analytic number theory that I am reading. I don't know how I should approach this. Is there a result I could use for this ? Nothing comes to my mind. I've tried for some time now and it's really bugging me that I can't figure it out. A hint or method would be appreciated, thanks.